# Dynamically return a variable number of models with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I currently have the code as seen below, I pass data from controller to my view and then display the data.

Using ajax I would like to adapt my view to be more dynamic with the data passed through the controller.

Goal:

At the moment, the view returns a list of names from people the user follows. I would like to have a set variable e.g. maxShow = 5, and when the page is loaded a maximum of 5 people will be shown. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, ajax will then get and place the next 5 onto the dom and this should be a continuous cycle.

I've been coming up with some rough pseudo code with the jquery as seen below for how to load every person dynamically, but cannot figure out how to limit the call to 5 people, and then another 5 people so on when scrolled to the very bottom. The only half-solution I have is to change my following query to .take(5) at the end.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       // Make an Ajax call 
     $.get("/Following",function(data){
      $("#div").html(data);
      });
     }
```

---

```
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Following()
        {
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            var following = _context.Followings
                            .Where(x => x.FollowerId == userId)
                            .Select(a => a.Followee)
                            .ToList();

            var viewModel = new FollowingViewModel
            {
                Following = following,
                ShowActions = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
                Heading = "People I'm following"
            };

            return View("following", viewModel);
        }
```

View

```
@model Gighub3.ViewModels.FollowingViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Following";
}

<h1>@Model.Heading</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var following in Model.Following)
    {
        <li>@following.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: You would need to have a global javascript variable for the 'counter' which you increment each time the ajax call is made, and pass that to the controller method so that you can use a `.Skip().Take()` in your query

Comment: in a particular scenario where for some external/business factor you cannot pass parameters through to the method for Skip and Take, how would you approach this? - how could you find a way of updating Skip ? @StephenMuecke

Comment: If the browser does not send a value to the server, then the server has no way of know what set of records you want next. Its not clear why you thing you cannot change the method to `public ActionResult Following(int page)`

Comment: Disregarding the code in my question, The ActionResult itself doesn't do the query, but calls a method getData() within the actionResult and getData() returns Task<FollowingViewModel> model (the data i want), and that model is passed over to ActionResult. However my ajax is made to ActionResult, for a business requirement reason I cannot pass parameters in task getData() and can't think of making use of params in the ActionResult since the query is done in getData(). Sorry if this is really poorly explained @StephenMuecke

Comment: You pass a value to your ActionResult method (say to an `int page` parameter), and then filter the results using `var data = getData().Skip(page * x).Take(x);` where `x` is the number of records you want (albeit, it wont be efficient since your `getData()` method is returing all records each time instead of querying the database and returning only the `x` records you want

Comment: I don't see where a page parameter comes into it ? thanks for your reply btw :) !

Comment: Would the parameters for take and skip be placed in ActionResult method then?

Comment: Because your initial ajax call will pass `page=1` - so you return records 6-10. `page` is then incremented in the browser so the next time you pass `page=2` which will return records 11-15 etc etc etc! Perhaps you should actually TRY IT

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to implement some sort of *pagination*. `_context.Followings` needs to have a sort by applied to it, and then add `limit` (number of results to be taken at a time e.g. 5) and `start` (which page you are currently on i.e. how many times has the person scrolled down to trigger a request for more followers) parameters to your ajax request. Then you can do something like:

```
_context.Followings.OrderBy(*/something in here*/).Skip((start - 1) * limit).Take(limit)
```